# Can I view properties stored on a function in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I do this in the the console

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.species = 'homo sapien';
```

then I type `Person`, I just see the function; but if I type `Person.species` I get back 'homo sapien'. I'd like to be able to see all properties that are stored on a function in the console. Is this possible?

Also, does anybody know of a good resource for explaining the mechanics behind what's happening here? I'm struggling with what it means for `Person` to be both a function and an object. Is the function being stored on some property of the `Person` object?

Comment: Is `Object.keys(Person);` enough? Otherwise you can create a raw object from it using something like `Object.keys(Person).reduce(function(m,k){m[k] = Person[k]; return m;}, {});`  Or simplest: Type `Person.` and look through the autocomplete list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`console.dir`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoledirobject):

```
console.dir(Person);
```

---

> I'm struggling with what it means for `Person` to be both a function and an object. Is the function being stored on some property of the `Person` object?

No. Every function is an object in JavaScript. They are just special objects because they are *callable*. Just like arrays are objects and also have some special internal behavior.

Comment: Right. So is there a way to think about/visualize the data structure itself? For example, I can grok a function stored on the property of an object like this: `{firstName: 'felix', lastName: 'Kling', fullName: function() {return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;}}`. But how is a function that is *itself* an object stored?

Comment: Actually, the `console.dir` output helped me. Thanks!

Comment: The function is stored like any other object/value. The only difference is that it has an *internal* property containing the functioncode. Like `{name: '...', [[Call]]: code}`. See also http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.